# block-grid not working in Foundation framework

Tags: grid, zurb-foundation, block

With the code below, what should be happening is each item should take up an equal amount of 3 per row. It should look like in a social website where each picture is the same width and height, and all columns equal. What's happening in this video is what I'm trying to accomplish:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7MPELEU_bFQ&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGD3PLy3DZHr6-LpCY7irPU8&index=4

NOTE: I am following the second part of the video, where the person talks about the block grid.

The images are not showing in block grid format. Instead , what's happening is the images are showing as a regular unordered list, with bullets, one on top of the other. It's not working like in the tutorial video.

Here is the code I used. All styles and JS files are set up properly. I'm using Foundation 6.8.0, the most recent one.

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Foundation Sandbox</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/foundation.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/icons/foundation-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/tutorial_styles.css">

</head>

<body>
<h2>Block Grid</h2>
    <div class="grid-container">


        <div class="grid-x">
            <ul class="medium-block-grid-3">
                <li><img src="https://get.foundation/sites/docs/assets/img/thumbnail/03.jpg"></li>
                <li><img src="https://get.foundation/sites/docs/assets/img/thumbnail/03.jpg"></li>
                <li><img src="https://get.foundation/sites/docs/assets/img/thumbnail/03.jpg"></li>
                <li><img src="https://get.foundation/sites/docs/assets/img/thumbnail/03.jpg"></li>
                <li><img src="https://get.foundation/sites/docs/assets/img/thumbnail/03.jpg"></li>
                <li><img src="https://get.foundation/sites/docs/assets/img/thumbnail/03.jpg"></li>
                <li><img src="https://get.foundation/sites/docs/assets/img/thumbnail/03.jpg"></li>
                <li><img src="https://get.foundation/sites/docs/assets/img/thumbnail/03.jpg"></li>
       

            </ul>
        </div>
    
    </div>
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/what-input.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/foundation.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).foundation();
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```